# How to open a new window with target='_blank' ? My code doesn't work

Tags: php, html, layout

```
$html=<<<html
<tr><td>$i.<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid target='_blank' ">$title</a></td><td>$count</td><td class="nowrap">$locationtext</td></tr>
html;
echo $html;
```

How to open a new window in the code above? `target='_blank'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `target` attribute is stuck inside your `href` attribute. Try this:

```
$html=<<<html
<tr><td>$i.<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid" target="_blank">$title</a></td><td>$count</td><td class="nowrap">$locationtext</td></tr>
html;
echo $html;
```

Comment: As written, this is insecure HTML and should be updated.  It should be `<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Click here</a>`.  See [The 2018 Guide to Building Secure PHP Software: Document Relationships](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software#rel-attribute) for details.  Otherwise, you might allow the target page to take control of the original page.

Answer (score 3):

look at the code output by that code. It will look like this:

```
<tr><td>$i.<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid target='_blank' ">$title</a></td><td>$count</td><td class="nowrap">$locationtext</td></tr>
```

and you want it to be

```
<tr><td>$i.<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid" target="_blank">$title</a></td><td>$count</td><td class="nowrap">$locationtext</td></tr>
```

That is:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you haven't separated your link attributes properly.  Try outputting the `href` and the `target` with proper separation (ie, close your quotes).

Use this:

```
<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid" target='_blank'>
```

instead of

```
<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid target='_blank' ">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="offtask.php?taskid=$taskid" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried putting the target="_blank" in a number of places, this code comes from a rss reader but I don't want people to click and leave my site but to just open another tab

`if($linked ) $msg = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="srssfetcher-link">'.$msg.'</a>';  // Puts a link to the posts`

Answer (score -2):

Use The target="_blank" in front of the href in php

Comment: The user already has target="_blank" in their code. Their problem was a mere misplacement of the end quote on the href